# How can I make my form autoscale correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ideally I want my form's `textarea` and everything below it to stay centered as the width of the browser changes. I am testing on Chrome. How do I make the form always stay centered and have the `textarea` width decrease as the browser's width decreases?

Note - I could only post 2 links in question, so please see my comment for a third image.

Half Screen (this is when you simply drag the right end of the browser to the left. Notice that the line where you add money has aligned left instead of center)

[image]

Minimum width screen (this is the furthest you can drag the edge of the browser to the left. The problem here is that the textarea's handle (bottom right corner) is no longer visible. I want the textarea's width to adjust to the browser's smaller dimension):

[image]

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline" align="center">

    <!-- Section to type question-->
        <div class="form-group" style="display:block">
            <textarea class="form-control" style="width:100%" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>

    <!--Section to add money---->
        <div class="input-group" id="AddMoney">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input id="EnterMoney" type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
        </div>

    <!--Section to add file-->
        <div id="AddFile">
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadFile').click(); return false;" />Add File</a>
            <input type="file" id="uploadFile" style="visibility: hidden;" />
        </div>

        <div id="imagePreview"></div>

    <!--Section for the Submit button-->
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
}
#imagePreview {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;   
    display: inline-block;
}
#AddMoney {
    width:150px;
    top:10px;
}
#AddFile {
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 

<!-- jQuery ui -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Full Screen (as the user plays with the dimensions of the browser, the form should always look like this):

http://imgur.com/GDNrwzV

Comment: Have a look at css media queries.

Comment: use bootsrap css grid system, you are already using their css for elements. Go to their docs css tab. Then get rid of your fixed widths

Comment: Ok I'm liking the grid system. It lets my form scale accordingly. But I don't understand how to integrate the media query code. On the site they just talk about them but do not explain how to use them. @m69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid off your css. Bootstrap takes care of everything itself. In your super simple case you don't even have to use media tags.

```css
  form {
    max-width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
  }
```

You can resize screen in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yv6vlKF7DhB1KfLfFCKn?p=preview) and see that everything is resizing.

Comment: I just deleted my comment about this not working. There's something wrong with my code. I only added certain parts of yours at first and saw that it wasn't working. However, when I completely wiped my index.php and just pasted everything you gave me it worked. I'm curious as to what the problem is. One thing I noticed differently was the 3 lines you gave linking to the bootstrap and jquery. Mine look different - I took them directly from bootstrap's [CDN links](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). See my edited answer above for the links

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. I didn't have a link to the bootstrap-css, only the javascript. Woops!

Comment: Just have a look carefully at places where you are using css with fixed widths and try to use bootstrap classes to define screen instead. Basically class="row" and classes like class="col-mid-5" is everything you need. Have a look at few examples:(http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: I noticed something else - it was because your "$" symbol was not in the special formatting provided by bootstrap as an input-group-addon. When I take the bootstrap CDN links directly from the bootstrap site, it works. I'm curious - why did you use the javascript and css links you used in your example?

Comment: I just created Plnkr from the Bootstrap template, that was provided by default for creating new Plnkers. Afterwards stuffed in your code partial, stripped away everything, that was not necessary from the template and that's it. I haven't probably stripped out everything, that was useless for sample.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added jQuery as a tag, I'm going to assume you're ok with using a jquery solution. What I recommend is a simple function that centers elements on window resize. It could look something like this:

```
function center(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    var width2 = width - $('#elementToCenter').width();
    var newMargin = width2 / 2;
    $('#elementToCenter').css("margin-left", newMargin);
}
$(window).resize(center);
```

The variable `width` represents the total width of the window.  To get the whitespace on either side of the element in question, subtract its width from that total to get `width2`. Now, divide that by 2 to get the amount of whitespace that belongs on each side.  Finally you can set that (`newMarin`) to the `margin-left` (or `margin-right` if you feel so inclined) and the element should display in the center of the page.

You might prefer this solution because the only framework it requires you to bring in is jQuery, and it looks like you've already done that.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello. It looks like your solution centers everything when I refresh the page, but not as the window resizes. http://imgur.com/41GJMHL This image is what happens when you stack the window to the left side of the screen only (Windows+left-button key I believe?). After making it as narrow as possible and then dragging it back to max width, this is what happens to the AddMoney element. http://imgur.com/wFKZSw1

Comment: Did you apply this function to all the elements you wanted to center? If there are a lot, you could put them in a wrapper div and apply the function to that. That way, the page content is aligned on the left but placed in the center of the page.

Comment: Well in the beginning it was just the AddMoney element that was giving me a hard time. But this didn't work for it :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, but...

Just get inside **[Boostrap.css](http://getbootstrap.com/)** to learn all this stuff. Download a free Bootstrap template to start learning.

**CSS FIX**

```
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin:50px auto 50px auto;
}

#imagePreview {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;   
    display: inline-block;
}

#AddMoney {
    width:150px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#AddMoney input {
width: 90%;
float:right;
}

#AddMoney span
{
width:5%;
}

#AddFile {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
}

form input,
form textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

/* Small to Medium screens or higher */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    form,
    form input,
    form textarea
    {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm...I've run into an anomaly using your solution. I tested this on Chrome, Mozilla firefox, and IE 11 for Windows 7 and they all resize the box in a weird way. If I stack the window to only the right side of my screen, then slowly expand it by dragging the left edge to the left, the AddMoney element visually resizes only on its right edge. When I _slowly_ reach the maximum width of the window, the AddMoney element reduced itself to about 20px. **But** if I instead drag the left edge _quickly_, the AddMoney element finishes at a size of about 125px. Are the browsers all just flawed?

Comment: Also, your solution was close but didn't quite get there. As I said in the above comment, the right edge of the AddMoney element moves to resize, but the left edge stays fixed, almost as if it were left-justified. All the other elements also stay left justified.

Comment: I have added some more CSS. May be that's what you are looking for. I hope you get what it does. There are many ways to get the same result.